# Удаление медиа сообщений

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Как удалять любые новые медиа сообщения в определенном чате?
Пробовал фильтровать с помощью `InputMessagesFilterPhotos` , но так и не понял как это совместить с `events.NewMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос таким способом.

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users=chat))
async def handler(event):
    if event.message.media != None:
        await event.delete()
```